# Twitter Bootstrap multiple dropdowns not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm having trouble with Twitter Bootstrap dropdowns. The first dropdown works but every other one doesn't. I found this post: [Bootstrap 2.1.1 dropdowns not working properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12671127/bootstrap-2-1-1-dropdowns-not-working-properly) but this is coded copied directly from the twitter bootstrap site and it worked before i upgraded to 2.0.

Here's a JSFiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/unWCN/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem resides in your `data-target` attributes. They should point to a specific dropdown parent, or to `#` if you use the default markup.

If you set `data-target="#"` for the dropdown togglers, your code works fine : [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sherbrow/unWCN/4/)

Note: if the `data-target` attribute is not present, the `href` will be used. Check [the plugin doc](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#dropdowns)

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be a [known bug](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/pull/4811) in Bootstrap 2.1.0 related to the data-target attribute, and will presumably be fixed in the next version.

In the meantime, you can apply one of the user-submitted fixes. This will involve modifying the `clearMenus` function in js/bootstrap-dropdown.js.

[Fix by SoapSeller:](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/commit/9f739736)

```
function clearMenus() { 
    $(toggle).parent().removeClass('open')  
}
```

[Fix by erlendfh:](https://github.com/erlendfh/bootstrap/commit/e9a648cd39dc6b5e0f126b7272adeac816ece758)

```
function clearMenus() {
    $(toggle).each(function () {
        getParent($(this)).removeClass("open")
    })
}
```

I haven't personally tested either of these, but SoapSeller linked [before](http://jsfiddle.net/6fAm3/2/) and [after](http://jsfiddle.net/fY849/2/) jsFiddles that illustrate his solution.

Comment: It does work if you keep the default `data-target="#"`, you should mention this workaround which is simpler with the default markup.

Comment: Thanks for the information on the bug. Good to know I wasn't doing something stupid. :)